# image requests page speed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i have a lot of small images (.png,.gif,.jpg) all kind of files.
When the page is getting requested for the first time.. each of these images which is placed in my App_Themes folder.. gets called.. one by one.. which slows down the page speed.

I have placed all my css and javascript in one file.. and call that file for everything related to css and js.. so is there anyway.. i can do the same for all the images??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the technique you are looking for is called Image Spriting and is described here on Stack Overflow by search for "CSS Sprites" or reading this fine blog http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/.  You will  need to convert these images to the same time in order for this to work (one large PNG, JPEG or GIF), or one of each type if their color spaces are incompatible.

Comment: hey thanks a lot.. i looked up.. for spriting images.. and it sounds cool.. but the thing is.. how will i specify the exact position in the large image file.. where the pic to be used is located..??? thanks anyway..:)